# Jquery Function not being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please why on earth isn't the function being call I have spent close to an hour on this:

This is the jquery:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#inner");

    // See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-400px"
        });
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }
}

$("button").bind("click", function() {
        alert("Hello");
    toggleDivs();
});
```

This is the head section in my html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PageScript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PageStyle.css">
</head>
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle or your button code.

Comment: create a fiddle and post html as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)your code is working fine.

2) use ready function to use bind function

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PageScript.js"></script>
      <script>

    function toggleDivs() {
    alert('hi');
    } 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button").bind("click", function() {
            alert("Hello");
        toggleDivs();
    });
     });  
        </script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Your head is incorrect. Kindly change the follow into this order:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PageScript.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PageStyle.css">
</head>
```

Explination:

Your PageScript.js will load first before the jquery.min.js because of this, all your jquery functions from your PageScript.js will cause an error.

Comment: Robert - Good Catch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
        alert("Hello");
    toggleDivs();
});
```

If its dynamic button use event delegation

```
$(document).on("click",'button',function() {
        alert("Hello");
    toggleDivs();
});
```

Scripts order wrong.Jquery must first and then others

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PageScript.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PageStyle.css">
</head>
```